# Apache Tomcat + Apache2 + mod_proxy: Issues regarding cluster

Tags: apache-2.2, java, mod-proxy, tomcat7, javascript

I have a `Tomcat 7.0.57` cluster setup behind an `Apache2` using `mod_proxy`.


**`Setup:`**

**Apache2**: 192.168.2.139
**Tomcat Node1**: ajp://192.168.2.166:8010 (http connector also defined on port 8082)
**Tomcat Node2**: ajp://192.168.2.166:8011 (http connector also defined on port 8083)

I have a Java web application (using `Jersey`, `ExtJS` and some other goodies), which is deployed using `Parallel Deployment`. Deployment works fine, and so does calling the application (using the Apache2 as the proxy, meaning **`http://http_proxy_ip/WebAppContext/app.html`**). The `ExtJS` front-end shows up fine.


**`WEB-INF/web.xml`** of the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <distributable />
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FGJobServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.freightgate.quartz.servlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FGJobServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/scheduler/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**`mod_proxy.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy balancer://testcluster>
      BalancerMember ajp://192.168.2.166:8010/ route=acd11-node01
      BalancerMember ajp://192.168.2.166:8011/ route=acd11-node02
      ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    </Proxy>

    # Excluding balancer-manager app to make it available on master
    ProxyPass /balancer-manager !

    ProxyPass / balancer://testcluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://testcluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid

    <Location /balancer-manager>
      SetHandler balancer-manager
    </Location>

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
      AllowOverride AuthConfig
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**`proxy`** definition within the ExtJS Model:

```
proxy : {
        type : 'rest',
        url : '/J_reportScheduler/scheduler/remotehost/scheduler',
        noCache: false,
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            successProperty : 'success',
            messageProperty : 'message',
        },
        writer : {
            type : 'json',
        }
}
```

**`Servlet definition in Java`**:

```
@Path("/{system}")
public class FGJobServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @POST
    @Path("/scheduler")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createJSON(
            JSONObject json,
            @PathParam("system") String system,
            @PathParam("cleanup") String cleanUp) {
       // logic goes here
    }
}
```

So, when the button gets clicked it fires a **`HTTP Post`** sending a JSON object to the Java backend using the URL **`/J_reportScheduler/scheduler/remotehost/scheduler`**.


When I run this locally from Eclipse, it just runs fine (**and it comes back with the URL of the Tomcat instance**). Running it in the Cluster gives me the following **`404 Not found`** and coming back with the URL from the HTTP server:

```
Remote Address:192.168.2.139:80
Request URL:http://192.168.2.139/J_reportScheduler/scheduler/remotehost/scheduler
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:193
Content-Type:application/json
Host:192.168.2.139
Origin:http://192.168.2.139
Referer:http://192.168.2.139/J_reportScheduler/app.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview source
{jobname: "ui101", description: "awd", startdate: "2015-01-21T00:00:00",…}
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 14 Jan 2015 23:32:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
```

**Calling the application directly on one of the cluster nodes using the `http connector` works fine as well**. So, I assume this has something to do with my `mod_proxy` setup. 


I've been struggling around with this for 2 days now, and I can't seem to make it work. Any help is much appreciated!


EDIT#1: Yes, I have checked Apache and Tomcat logs, just Apache showing the 404. Application log doesn't show anything as well.


EDIT#2: Just in case it wasn't obvious: **`HTTP Get`** requests work just fine.

Comment: Try remove trailing slash from `BalancerMember ajp://192.168.2.166:8010` and `BalancerMember ajp://192.168.2.166:8011`

Comment: That did the trick! Don't know why I didn't see that! Thanks a lot man! Post it a an answer so I could upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove trailing slash from `balancermember`:

```
<Proxy balancer://testcluster>
  BalancerMember ajp://192.168.2.166:8010 route=acd11-node01
  BalancerMember ajp://192.168.2.166:8011 route=acd11-node02
  ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
```

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51982